# Getting Rome via Maven

Tags: maven, rome

I'm working with Maven and I'm looking to start using Rome for a project.

When I look for "rome" in my Eclipse's m2 instance, I get a few results:

1. net.java.dev.rome:rome:1.0.0 (2010-04-17)
2. org.rometools:rome-fetcher:1.2 (2011-03-11) <-- most recent
3. rome:rome:1.0 (2010-05-10)

On top of that, the rome project seems to be now on rometools.jira.com, as far as I can tell. And [this page](https://rometools.jira.com/wiki/display/ROME/ROME+and+Maven+2) seems to say to use the third option, but *on another repository* (other than Maven central), even though the same page states that it's not up to date.

So I'm lost. If I want the latest version of the Rome library, what Maven dependency should I use? Am I even using the right repository after all?

Answer (score 3):

If someone is nowadays looking for latest Rome library, the [newest version is 1.5.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rometools/rome/1.5.0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.rometools</groupId>
    <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
     <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

more information at http://rometools.github.io/rome/

Comment: http://rometools.github.io/rome/ROMEReleases/index.html shows only 1.0 -- I don't get it.  Can I just download the JAR for 1.5.0?

Comment: The rometools web page is probably not updated, but Maven central has the 1.5.0 version: http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/rometools/rome/1.5.0/rome-1.5.0.jar

Comment: assuming paranoia, how do you know that's actually the JAR from rome tools?  Or, do they build it from source?  It must come from somewhere..

Comment: The tagged source for 1.5.0 release is here: https://github.com/rometools/rome/releases/tag/rome-1.5.0 I actually build it from source for myself, latest development version is 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT.