# Getting and running Rome

Tags: java, maven, rss, rome, syndication-feed

A few related questions:

What's the [version number for the latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26150106/262852) for Rome?
Where can I [download the JAR](http://rometools.github.io/rome/ROMEReleases/index.html) for the latest version?
Where does [maven get its JAR](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rometools/rome/1.5.0) for Rome?

finally,

Rome is, objectively, numerically, the most frequently use Java API for parsing RSS feeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the version number for the latest version for Rome?

According to your research: 1.5.0   :-)

> Where can I download the JAR for the latest version?

One place would be Maven Central.  You can use http://search.maven.org/ to find the 1.5.0 version.

> Where does maven get its JAR for Rome?

Maven will get the JAR from Maven Central ... unless you set your maven configs and/or your POM file to get it from somewhere else;

Note that different people seem to have uploaded Rome to Maven over time ... with different "groupids".  It looks like "com.rometools" is the official groupid now.

> Rome is, generally, the preferred, or at least, most used, Java API for parsing RSS feeds?

I'm **NOT** touching that one.  It calls for an opinion-based answer.

Comment: read "most frequently used" instead of "preferred"...more quantitative (sorta kinda, hard to cite hard numbers, however).

Comment: Do you **seriously** imagine anyone has tried to get hard numbers??  That's really still a subjective question ... "dressed up" as objective one.  Not touching it!